# qt plugin fails to load ("not a valid qt plugin")

Tags: qt, plugins

we have a application, which loads several plugins (audio/videocodec related). All plugins except one plugin are getting loaded correctly.
The message i get is `The file "foobar.codec" is not a valid Qt plugin` (and `QPluginLoader::load ()` returns false)

The strange thing about this is, that the identical plugin works for every other developer in our team, and on non-development machines aswell - And i havent changed any source files or project settings of that codec (it is a fresh svn checkout).

On the Qt documentation page, ive read that setting the enviroment variable `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS` to 1, will give me more debug output on the console, but that was not the case.

And deleting all entries in the plugin cache referring to the plugin in question hasnt changed anything aswell.

The setup:
Qt 4.3.3
Windows XP SP3
VS 2005 (crt-version: 8.0.50727.4053)

**EDIT:**
Just found this [faq-entry](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/faq/answer/my_applications_plugins_wont_load_on_some_windows_machines_what_can_be_wron). I will check tomorrow if the dependencies are alright...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the dependency dlls of the plugin dll was not in the correct path